# How to include excluded file types in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, manifest

Currently MSBuild is not copying over files w/ the .manifest extension to my build drop folder.  I've added commands to explicitly copy over the file, but is there a config flag that I can set so that .manifest files are included?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass the `AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions` property to your build.  The property's value should be a semi-colon separated list of file extensions.  From `Microsoft.Common.targets`:

```
<!--
These are the extensions that reference resolution will consider when looking for files related
to resolved references.  Add new extensions here if you want to add new file types to consider.
-->
<AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions Condition=" '$(AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions)' == '' ">
    .pdb;
    .xml
</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
```

There is no way to add values to the list.  You can only supply the whole list, so make sure you include the defaults, e.g.,

```
MSBuild.exe MyProject.csproj /t:build "/p:AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions=.pdb;.xml;.manifest"
```

Comment: I added AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions element a child to a PropertyGroup element to my build script and also to the .csproj file and didn't see the files being copied over (I have an automated build running through TFS).  

Does this assume the files are the output of a project (i.e. bin folder)? If so, do you know what I would need to do to get my automated build to copy over files that aren't outputs of a project?

Comment: @JM Yes.  MSBuild will only grab files that are in the obj output directory for your project.  If your .manifest file isn't in the output directory, you'll probably need to add a post-build target to your .csproj file.

Comment: As an aside, you can add values to the list: `<AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>$(AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions);.manifest</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>`  That ought to do the trick.